# Return null from generic method

Tags: c#, .net

How do I return null value from a generic method?

```
protected T ValueOrDefault<T>(IDataReader reader, int ordinalId)
        {  
  Type t = typeof(reader.GetValue(ordinalId));
    if (t.IsValueType){
        //Struct. How do I return null?
    } else { 
        //Class
        //just return  null
        return  default(T);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the whole method (at least include the signature).

Comment: On a side note, 'typeof' will not work as you've written it.  You'll need to use GetType() and possibly check that GetValue has not returned null.

Comment: Trying to alter the return signature of a method at runtime would tear a hole in the universe.

Comment: BTW - do you anticipate getting reference types from your reader?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning null value from generic method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452794/returning-null-value-from-generic-method)

Comment: No this is not a duplicate. He want's different overloads for class and struct constraints. Anyway default(T) will return null for a class and the ``zero`` value for a value type so you can just use ``default(T)`` all the time

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`default(T)` works in both cases.

Comment: I have to return Nullable<> if T is value type, but not default(T).

Comment: @Alex, if you return Nullable<T>, then you're violating the contract of the method, which is supposed to return type T.  If T is already an `int?`, however, then the `default(T)` will work.

Answer (score 4):

`default(T)` does function in both cases, but its meaning is slightly different for value types.  It literally returns the default value of the type.  In the case of `Method<int>`, it will return `0`, not `null`.

**UPDATE:**  Given your method signature:

```
protected T ValueOrDefault<T>(IDataReader reader, int ordinalId)
```

You can't return `Nullable<T>` in the case of a value type and type `T` in the case of a reference type. That would have to be two different methods.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you can only return `null` if the return type is either `Nullable<T>` or a reference type. Normal value-types have no `null`.

For reference types `default(T)` is `null`, and for `Nullable<T>` it's null too. So you can use `default(T)` in both cases where `null` exists.

If the type is another value-type `default(T)` will not be `null`, but since there is no `null` that wouldn't make sense anyways.

---

It is not possible to simply have a method that has return type `T` if `T` is a reference-type/`Nullable<T>` and `T?` for normal value types.

One could try to define something like this, but it won't compile because the compiler doesn't understand that the generic constraints are mutually exclusive. It just doesn't consider generic constraints for that.

```
T? a<T>()
  where T:struct
{
}

T a<T>()
  where T:class
{
}
```

You need to make these methods different in some other way. Either by using different names or different parameters.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return `T?` if it's a value type, you have to use two separate methods. However, there is a complexity, in that methods can't differ only by their return type (there's also issues around the generic args not being part of a method signature). So you have to provide a 'stub' method parameter which the compiler uses to resolve which method to call:

```
public T MyMethod<T>(T stub) where T : class {
    // ...
    return null;
}

public T? MyMethod<T>(T? stub) where T : struct {
    // ...
    return null;
}

// this will then compile...
string s = MyMethod<string>(null);
int? i = MyMethod<int>(null);
```

Comment: Why not? The overload resolution algorithm will choose the correct one at runtime. Any duplicated code can be put in a third method called by the other two that returns a boolean indicating if null should be returned. What you want to do _is not possible_ in the current C# language.

Answer (score 1):

It's not legal to return `null` for an unconstrained `T` value.  Consider for instance if `T` is instantiated as a value type.  In that case `null` would not be a legal value and hence the code is illegal.

What you're looking for is `default(T)`.  This will work for both value and reference types.  For reference types it will produce `null` and for value types it will produce the zero initialized value.

Answer (score 1):

In C# 9, it is possible to have a single method return null for reference and for nullable value types. Note that string and string? are exactly the same type but int and int? are different (Int32 and Nullable).

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGenericNull()
{
  static T? GetDefault<T>(bool wantNullable) => wantNullable ? default(T?) : default(T);

  string? s1 = GetDefault<string>(false);
  Assert.IsNull(s1);
  string? s2 = GetDefault<string>(true);
  Assert.IsNull(s2);

  int? d1 = default(int);
  Assert.AreEqual(d1, 0);
  int? d2 = default(int?);
  Assert.IsNull(d2);

  int? n1 = GetDefault<int>(false);
  Assert.AreEqual(n1, 0);
  int? n2 = GetDefault<int>(true);
  Assert.AreEqual(n2, 0); // Expected default(int?), i.e. Nullable<int> with no value.

  int? n4 = GetDefault<int?>(false);
  Assert.IsNull(n4);
  int? n5 = GetDefault<int?>(true);
  Assert.IsNull(n5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To see why this isn't possible, try replacing `T` with a value type:

```
protected int ValueOrDefault<int>(IDataReader reader, int ordinalId)
        {  
  Type t = typeof(reader.GetValue(ordinalId));
    if (t.IsValueType){
        //Struct. How do I return null?
    } else { 
        //Class
        //just return  null
        return  default(int);
    }
}
```

If the return type is int, you can't return `null` because it's not a valid value.  The type of T would have to be nullable in the first place, in which case `default(T)` works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just `return default` without (T) at the end. C# 7.1 or above.